# How to groupby non-unique timedate index and column

Tags: python, pandas

Just starting with Pandas. I have a DataFrame with a timedate index a number of columns (data from parsing a log file). I have been able to convert the DataFrame index to a period index (monthly). One of the columns contains the user name associated to the event in the logfile. I would like to get an overview of the number of occurrences (i.e. rows in the DataFrame) per month per user. The index has non-unique values, so I have been able to group this by using

`grp = DF_monthly.groupby(level=0)`

However, I don't seem to be able to add that extra grouping on the user column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your raw log looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

infile = StringIO("""datetime,user,event
2013-01-01 11:15:23,A,error
2013-01-02 11:15:23,C,warning
2013-01-03 11:15:23,C,message
2013-02-01 11:15:23,A,error
2013-02-02 11:15:23,B,warning
2013-02-03 11:15:23,A,message""")

df = pd.read_csv(infile, parse_dates=True, index_col='datetime')

                    user    event
datetime                         
2013-01-01 11:15:23    A    error
2013-01-02 11:15:23    C  warning
2013-01-03 11:15:23    C  message
2013-02-01 11:15:23    A    error
2013-02-02 11:15:23    B  warning
2013-02-03 11:15:23    A  message
```

Then you can get a count per user per month with:

```
df.groupby([lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%b'), 'user']).count()['event']

          user
2013-Feb  A       2
          B       1
2013-Jan  A       1
          C       2
```

So its not necessary to groupby month first, unless you have other reasons to do so. If so, you can also apply the last groupby on the monthly df as well.

The lambda function converts each timestamp from the index to a string of 'Year-Month' and performs a groupby on that string.

Comment: Thanks. I should now be able to convert that into a crosstab so that I can make a plot from it.